# "unlink permission denied" error trying to delete deleteme.txt

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, unlink

I want to delete deleteme.txt in the Ubuntu web server.

So I made `4.php` do the following:

```
<?php
unlink('deleteme.txt');
?>
```

deleteme.txt has the following permission status:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu    19 Jun 12 06:18 deleteme.txt
```

When I execute "4.php", this error always occurs

```
Warning: unlink(deleteme.txt): Permission denied in /var/www/html/4.php on line 2
```

I already tried `chmod 777 deleteme.txt` and `chown ubuntu /var/www/html` on the directory which contains "deleteme.txt"

I also tried `chown ubuntu /var/www/` on the parent directory of that file.

Comment: Do you have write permission to the directory the file is in?

Comment: Maybe try an absolute path? unlink('/var/www/deleteme.php');

Comment: chowning to ubuntu is pointless if this script is not running as the ubuntu user, or doesn't have write pmermissions to start with.

Comment: @kver it doesn't work. Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/deleteme.txt): Permission denied in /var/www/html/4.php on line 2

Comment: @Majenko I didn't realize the write permission in the directory the file is in is the troublemaker for me. I typed "chmod 777 /var/www/html" and the delete operation worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: When you delete a file you're not writing to the file, you're writing to the directory the file is in - useful thing to remember.

Comment: @Majenko Thank you so much. If you were in my house, I will buy a cool beer for you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to chown to `www-data`, thus meaning that the `www-data` will gain ownership of the file allowing you to delete it through unlink with php.

Like so:

```
$ chown www-data <file or folder>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had needed to change mode of the directory into capable of writing. I just changed the owner of the directory. but that doesn't do. writing permission of not only files but also "the present Directory the files is in"