# Trying to delete an image through php script

Tags: php, apache, permissions

Hello im trying to make a script that deletes some images from the server.
I read every single post about unlink() and the major permissions / wrong directory errors , [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594898/permission-denied-php-unlink) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929101/php-permission-denied-using-unlink-and-rmdir) and i tried every solution i found but still cant find whats wrong.

```
 $baseDir=dirname(__DIR__).'/media/com_iproperty/pictures/';
 $deleteImage=$prefix.'_'.$imgParts[0].'.'.$imgParts[$imgLen-1];
 var_dump($deleteImage); //196040_DSCN2675.JPG
 $deleteThumb=$prefix.'_'.$imgParts[0].'_thumb.'.$imgParts[$imgLen-1];
 $user='root';
 var_dump($baseDir); ///var/www/vhosts/spiti360.gr/httpdocs/demo2/media/com_iproperty/pictures/
 $commandyo='rm '.$baseDir.$deleteImage;
 if (file_exists($baseDir.$deleteImage)) {
   echo "exists";
   chown($baseDir.$deleteImage,$user);
   chmod($baseDir.$deleteImage,0777);
   //system($commandyo);
   unlink($baseDir.$deleteImage);
 }                         
 die();
```

I always take as output the "exists" string, that means that the file exists and it isnt a directory error.

When i use :

```
root@server ~ # locate 196040_DSCN2675.JPG
```

**Output:**

```
/var/www/vhosts/spiti360.gr/httpdocs/demo2/media/com_iproperty/pictures/196040_DSCN2675.JPG
```

The image didnt deleted.

I enabled the error display and i take this:

```
Warning: chown(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/spiti360.gr/httpdocs/demo2/custom_scripts/eAgentSingle.php on line 562

Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/spiti360.gr/httpdocs/demo2/custom_scripts/eAgentSingle.php on line 563
```

Im using both `chown` and `chmod` on file and i also `chmod 777` on pictures folder as i read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187176/unlink-permission-denied-error-trying-to-delete-deleteme-txt) but nothing seems to change.

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 26333184 Jul  6 13:33 pictures
```

I even tried to use system and rm command but didnt work also.
I aknowledge that this is a permission error , but whatever solution i used found from stackoverflow or google wont work.

Do i miss something ?

EDIT:
I used : `chown -R root:www-data /var/www/vhosts/spiti360.gr/httpdocs/demo2/media/com_iproperty/pictures/`

and i set usergroup for pictures folder to www-data

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root www-data 26333184 Jul  6 14:15 pictures
```

But still doesnt work.

Comment: with phpinfo(); take a look to the directive 'disable_functions'.

Comment: Im root  and disable_function has no value .

Answer (score 0):

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 26333184 Jul  6 13:33 pictures
```

You have to set the user and/or group to www-data, i can't remember if both have to be, otherwise apache won't have permissions to delete it.

Comment: Only the group needs to be www-data

Comment: I used this : `root@server ~ # sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/vhosts/spiti360.gr/httpdocs/demo2/media/com_iproperty/pictures/`


`drwxrwxrwx 2 root www-data 26333184 Jul  6 13:33 pictures`

Still wont work.

Comment: You tried to edit the group on the image too ? Since you're trying to chmod and chown on the image, the image has to have group too.

Comment: Yeap i used chgrp to www-data on image also

Comment: Can i ask why you're doing the chmod and chown just before deleting a image ? Have you tried just to unlink it directly ?